# Javascript: Avoid global variable in code involving lots of loops

Tags: javascript, loops, global-variables

I'm having a very confusing problem. I think it is best explained with code:

```js
var length = 0; // I want to avoid this variable being global

function loop(array, func) {
 for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
  array[i].func(length);
  length += array[i].number;
  if (func) {
   func();
  }
 }
}

function bar(number) {
 this.func = function(len) {
  console.log(len);
 };
 this.number = number;
}

function main() {
 var array = [];
 for (var j = 1; j < 3; j++) {
  var foo = new bar(j);
  array.push(foo);
 }
 loop(array, function() {
  loop(array);
 });
}

main();
```

I have a loop similar to this in some other code. I simply cannot figure out how to make the length variable local in this code. I cannot pass it to the function because it calls itself. I cannot really move it anywhere because the loops keep messing things up.

Thank you for any help!

Comment: when you declare `i` and `j` in `for loop`, declare using `let` instead of `var`

Comment: @Isaac this isn't using ES6, it's just for a website that I want to be backwards compatible

Comment: @Isaac While good advice in general, that won't solve anything here

Comment: What about as a class member?

Comment: Can you explain more what you want to achieve or what the input and output are?  People can help you with those details. Maybe you're solving your problem in a more complicated way than it needs to be.

Comment: @Viet This is a very generalised example. Any more information that I give will only make it more confusing. The only part that makes it complicated is the nested loops, which cannot be avoided. The only thing that matters is that the length variable is incremented correctly with each call of the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure *exactly* what you're trying to accomplish with all this, but it looks like `main` is the caller of `loop`, so you can have `length` be an argument to `loop` and have `main` call `loop` with an initial `length` of 0 and have `loop` and the callback return the altered `length`s:

```js
function loop(array, length, func) {
  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    array[i].func(length);
    length += array[i].number;
    if (func) {
      length = func(length);
    }
  }
  return length;
}

function bar(number) {
  this.func = function(len) {
    console.log(len);
  };
  this.number = number;
}

function main() {
  var array = [];
  for (var j = 1; j < 3; j++) {
    var foo = new bar(j);
    array.push(foo);
  }
  loop(array, 0, function(newLen) {
    return loop(array, newLen);
  });
}

main();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this! The code in my original post is just a generalised version of my actual code so the problem is made slightly more obvious. I think I will use your version since it makes a bit more sense to me.

Answer (score 3):

I'm assuming that you want to maintain the value of length between successive function calls of loop. You can do this by returning a closure that uses the length. So, instead of defining loop as you currently do, you could do something like this:

```
const loop = (function() {
    var length = 0;
    return function (array, func) {
        // Your current code for loop here
    }
}) ();
```

Basically, what this does is it assigns loop to be a function that is returned from another anonymous function call. This ensures that the value of length persists because it is defined outside of the scope of the function that is eventually assigned to loop, but is entirely inaccessible anywhere else in the code.

Answer (score 1):

[Keveloper's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50959479/2045384) is a good idea for you. And I would suggest you try that way first.

Here is another way to avoid global variable which may also work.

```js
function loop(array, func, data) {
 for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
  array[i].func(data.length);
  data.length += array[i].number;
  if (func) {
   func(data);
  }
 }
}

function bar(number) {
 this.func = function(len) {
  console.log(len);
 };
 this.number = number;
}

function main() {
 var array = [];
 for (var j = 1; j < 3; j++) {
  var foo = new bar(j);
  array.push(foo);
 }
 loop(array, function (data) {
  loop(array, null, data);
 }, { length: 0 });
}

main();
```

You may pass the length as a parameter of `loop`. But not directly, use a object to wrap it, so it passed by *reference*.